# Postgres backup to plaintext, drop data on restore?

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking to backup a postgres database to a plaintext file, and then restore that backup. Here is what I tried.

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump --create mydatabase > backup.sql
sudo -u postgres psql < backup.sql
```

I want the database to be completely restored to the state it was in when I backed it up. I'm expecting it to issue a DROP DATABASE in backup.sql, but this is not happening.

Currently, my work-around is to edit backup.sql and insert a DROP DATABASE. Is that really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the best you can do with the default `pg_dump` is `--clean` (incompatible with `--create`) which doesn't drop the database, but does add commands to individually drop all of the tables and other objects that are being backed up.  If you load a file made this way, if someone's added a new table since the backup that new table will remain in the database.

You could create a wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "DROP DATABASE $1;"
sudo -u postgres pg_dump --create $1
```

And then run `mybackupscript.sh mydatabase > backup.sql` (or move the `sudo` command out of the script and run the script with sudo, your choice.)

Answer (score 0):

In your shell script you can use `dropdb` command.